# Qual a real diferença entre um button e um imageButton?

Tags: android, button

**A imagem que usei para fazer os testes é uma engrenagem simples de dimensões 100x100 com o fundo transparente.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo de início notei que diferentemente do **Button**, ao criar um **ImageButton** você é obrigado a adicionar uma imagem ao mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que **se nenhuma imagem é selecionada, a sua criação fica impossibilitada** (o que faz todo o sentido).

Eu selecionei uma imagem para que eu pudesse criar o ImageButton e logo de cara percebi é que atrás da imagem (engrenagem) aparece uma "paradinha cinza" cobrindo todo o seu fundo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas e aí? É só isso? Eu poderia muito adicionar um background a um button normal e obteria o mesmo efeito, além de não ter essa "**paradinha cinza inútil**" atrás.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Seguindo com os testes** => Quando aumentei o tamanho do Button de 100x100 para 150x150, obviamente que a qualidade da resolução da imagem diminuiu, mas ao fazer isso com o ImageButton o tamanho da engrenagem permaneceu o mesmo e o que aumentou foi a "**paradinha cinza inútil**" atrás da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais uma coisa que também acontece no Button que não acontece no ImageButton, é que ao setar o background do Button, se o mesmo possuir algum texto e o mesmo não for retirado, ele continua aparecendo, **entrando assim em conflito com a imagem**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em favor do ImageButton (dependendo da necessidade) notei que ao clicar no mesmo, há um efeito no click. É simples, mas há:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**No Button também há esse efeito, mas somente quando não é setado nenhum background no mesmo.**

Na MainActivity a declaração e utilização de ambos é mesma:

```js
package genesysgeneration.classsound;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button button;
    private ImageButton imageButton2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageButton2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageButton2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.button:

                Intent it01 = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(it01);
                break;

            case R.id.imageButton2:

                Intent it02 = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(it02);
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Em todo o post, citei quase que todas as vezes o "**troço cinza**" que é criado atrás da imagem do ImageButton como "**paradinha cinza inútil**", mas ele (ImageButton) **pode e deve ter alguma utilidade**, só ainda não sei  qual.

Gostaria de saber em **quais casos seria preferível utilizar um ImageButton em vez de um Button** e **quais as suas reais diferenças que não essas**, que considero mínimas e não apresentam necessariamente uma funcionalidade maior e/ou melhor.

Comment: cara, no android, voce pode usar qualquer coisa como um button desde que voce implemente o metodo **componente.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ...{});** dai tanto faz ser um layout, um button, um imageview, um toglebutton, e por ai vai, lembrando que voce pode criar um arquivo .xml na pasta drawable com um "selector" para criar qualquer efeito que queira usando imagens e os itens "state_checked=true ou false" para mudar a visalização do componente

Comment: vivendo e aprendendo ^-^ acho muito interessante essas possibilidades que o android studio proporciona

Comment: Você pode remover a paradinha cinza usando isso: `style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` e depois isso pra adicionar um efeito de clique: `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As diferenças advêm da classe de que cada uma descende.

[Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) descende de TextView. Torna um TextView clicável adicionando um efeito visual ao ser clicado.

[ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) descende de ImageView. Torna uma ImageView clicável adicionando um efeito visual ao ser clicado.

Assim, o *foreground* de um Button, atribuido por `android:text=""`, é um texto, enquanto no ImageButton, atribuido por `android:src=""` é uma imagem.

Em ambos é possível alterar o background, mas o efeito visual, ao ser clicado, pode ser perdido se o drawable escolhido não tiver [estados](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

A escolha entre um e outro depende do *foreground* que pretende, texto ou imagem.

Comment: Pra um efeito visual mais bonitinho, geralmente uso: `style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` e `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless‌​"`...

Comment: Assim você tira o "background cinza" padrão e deixa apenas sua imagem com um efeito de clique

Comment: Eu não sabia que podia classificar como descendência do `TextView` em relação ao `Button`. +1

Comment: Então em termos de funcionalidade não diferem em nada? Não existem casos em que um seja extremamente necessário e que o outro não? A utilização de um e de outro é mais por comodidade e/ou praticidade?

Comment: Ambos são botões, então, em termos de funcionalidade eles são iguais. Como eu disse na resposta, a escolha depende, principalmente, se quer ter um texto ou uma imagem no botão.